# Why is angular-toastr not accepting the overriden postionClass.?

Tags: angularjs, angular-toastr

Plugin used: https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

My intention is to create a toastr that spans the full with of the page on top and [according to the documentation](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html), `positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'` will do the trick.

```
toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!', {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
});
```

A peek into the plugins css also validate the claim.

```
.toast-top-full-width {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But somehow, the code doesn't work. Whats wrong with my code?
Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2O6hjk5vnMUWWULNK9hs?p=preview

Comment: Toasts cannot override the position class, only via config as the answers say.

Comment: @Jesus: thanks. I saw the source now. why so? Is a future version coming that will override the `positionClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the toast in the angular config.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'toastr']);

 app.config(function(toastrConfig) {
   angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
   });
 });

 app.controller('toastr-demo', function($scope, toastr) {
    toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
 });
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pdstz2WkJqdi1Qw0R1pX?p=preview

Comment: I removed the answer tag because console shows me this when logging toastr. `success(message, title, optionsOverride)` why isn't overridden?

Comment: Because its not written in the source to override. thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `toastContainer` is not big enough, you should add a config like :

```
app.config(function(toastrConfig) {
  angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
  });
});
```

This way, the container of all your toast will be full width, and then when you call a toast you can set his size to full-width.